# Create a folder with all possible combinations of characters and numbers

Tags: linux, filenames, case-sensitivity

I want to create a folder like "example.txt, example.Txt, example.TxT... all possible combinations.

Comment: a "filename" like "example.txt" *implies* a *file* not a "folder" / directory; are you sure you want directories named like that?  Also, should the upper & lower-casing happen with the "example" letters?

Comment: It depends on the underlying filesystem. Some may be case insensitive...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With shells with csh-style brace-expansion support:

```
mkdir example.{t,T}{x,X}{t,T}
```

With `zsh`, you can shorten it to:

```
mkdir example.{tT}{xX}{tT}
```

if you enable the `braceccl` option (which I wouldn't otherwise recommend enabling globally as it kinds of conflicts with some other usages of braces) with `set -o braceccl`.

If you want *all possible combinations of letters and numbers*, assuming you want to limit to ascii letters and numbers (and not the thousands of other letters and numbers of different scripts in Unicode), with `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh93`:

```
mkdir example.{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}}
```

Which with `zsh -o braceccl` you can shorten to:

```
mkdir example.{a-zA-Z0-9}{a-zA-Z0-9}{a-zA-Z0-9}
```

But as that's 238328 ((26+26+10)<sup>3</sup>) directories, you may reach the `execve()` limit on the size of arguments and environment. You could work around that by using the builtin `mkdir` in `zsh` (by doing `zmodload zsh/files`) or doing:

```
 printf '%s\n' example.{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{A..Z},{0..9}} |
   xargs -0 mkdir
```

Comment: can you help me ?
home/example_one/example_two/example_three/.......example_billion
i want to show last locations and get info

Comment: @Irakli, if you have a separate question, please ask it as a new question here, if possible with more details as I'm not sure I understand what you mean from your short description.